# "Josera" vs "Happy Cat" kitten dry food

Tags: cats, diet

I am going buy a new brand dry food for my 6-month-old kittens because they don't eat their last brand - [Fidaar](http://iranfp.com/) - anymore.

I Asked local pet shops and they have two brands of kitten dry food - Josera and Happy Cat.

Which one do you think i should buy?

Comment: when a cat is 6-months old it is no longer a kitten so you can start feeding food for a young adult cat.i do not know any of the brands you mention,to find a good quality food you need to read the label of the food it needs to be high in meat and low in fillers.

Comment: There are a lot of resources available on what's nutritionally necessary and appropriate for a cat; you can look up this information, then use it to read the labels and make the decision yourself. As an aside, a 6-month cat is still a kitten, but a "kitten formula" isn't necessary at that point. High protein and sufficient calories to continue fueling growth is what's important until ~12-18 months (longer for some breeds).

Answer (score -1):

Both. Alternate them. How would you feel if you would need to eat always the same?

This is why they don't eat also the Fidaar. They will, just they need also some different.

Note also, only giving dry food to cats is cruel. Give them regularly, ideally every day, some other, too (ideally, raw flesh or fish, but never raw pork).

If costs matter you, you can use anything and any organ. They eat their pray in the wild as it is.

The like bloody hearth at most, and also lungs. Better if it is as it came from the butcher, without washing, because the odor of the blood excites them.

Comment: Cats tend to have sensitive digestive systems, and sudden changes can cause a great deal of gastric distress. Changing flavors within the same line can be okay, but changing lines or brands will cause issues. Additionally, random raw chunks of meat are risky and not nutritionally complete. Proper preparation of a raw diet involves a fair amount of effort. A cat should eat wet or raw foods to get sufficient hydration, but with appropriate label-reading, or research and preparation in the case of a homemade diet.

Comment: Have you got a source that backs up the statement you've made about only feeding dry food being cruel?

Comment: https://m.petmd.com/dog/nutrition/evr_multi_is_it_okay_to_play_switcheroo_with_your_pet_foods https://www.petsmart.com/learning-center/cat-care/when-should-i-change-my-cats-diet/A0069.html#out_new https://www.hillspet.com/cat-care/nutrition-feeding/switching-cat-food citations to back up my "surreal" claim, not to mention the noxious diarrhea when I switched two kittens too fast due to lack of availability. This SE deals with the health and well being of living animals. Correctness is extremely important.

Comment: @GraySheep - If you've got an issue with a comment that breaks the 'Be Nice' policy please flag it. I've removed your previous comment because your description of this site, which many people work to make great, is inaccurate and isn't very nice. I don't own cats and I personally don't have any experience with them. I'm asking for a source because I'd _love to read more about it_ not to try and catch you out. For more information about writing great answers please read [answer].